# exposing properties from a jQuery plugin attached to multiple elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

It has been suggested to me the following structure is preferred/standard to expose public properties from a jQuery plugin.

```
(function($) {
   $.myPlugin = {
       data: {}
   };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The above example exposes 'data' through the syntax `$.myPlugin.data.`

If the plugin is attached to multiple HTML elements on a page, then I think $.myPlugin.data becomes invalid as it is the equivalent of a static variable.

1. What is another way to write the plugin so .data is related to the instance of a particular plugin?
2. How would one reference this property through code external to the plugin?  ie.  how do you read the property?

Comment: You can have a look at how most jQuery UI widgets are implemented. The they often accept three parameters, such as `.myPlugin('option', key [, value]))` to get or set options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would attach the data to each element the plugin operates on.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        myPlugin: function (options) {
            var defaultConfig = {data: {}};
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).data(
                   "myPlugin", $.extend(defaultConfig, options)
                );
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

For example when called like this:

```
$("div.foo").myPlugin({option: "value"});
```

Each `<div class="foo">` would have its own copy of

```
{
   data: {},
   option: "value"
}
```

available at `$(this).data("myPlugin")`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using callback functions?

```
// external code
$('.something').myPlugin({
    onLoad : function(object, data) {
        // use data here
    }
});
```